# Manipulating Hypergeometric functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-equations, special-functions

I have a differential equation:

$$(f\Phi')'-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}\Phi=0,$$

which I've solved with a program that yields

$$\Phi(r)=C_1 (\frac{r}{R})^{2}{_2 }F_1 (1-l,2+l,3,\frac{r}{R}).$$

While this technically works, I want this to be in the following form:

$$\Phi_<(r)=C_1 (\frac{r}{r_0})^{l+1}_{} {_2 }F_1 (-l-1,-l+1,-2l,\frac{R}{r})$$ when $r<r_0$

and

$$\Phi_>(r)=C_2 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{l}{_2 }F_1 (l,l+2,2l+2,\frac{R}{r})$$ when $r>r_0$

for some arbitrary distance $r_0 >R$. Also, $f=1-\frac{R}{r}.$

Both of the above functions satisfy my differential equation, so there must be a way to write each of these functions in terms of the one that my program found. Can someone give me a few pointers?
For a little extra context, my solution corresponds to the potential that some particle feels outside a black hole in Schwarzschild spacetime where $R$ is the location of the event horizon and $r_0$ is the instantaneous position of the particle.

Comment: This is a well-written question, but is there not a paper studying your GR problem? (Maybe I haven't understood your description too well - but it sounds like a standard kind of GR problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a substitution $x\equiv r/R$ one can transform the ODE into a hypergeometric equation:
$$x(1-x)\phi''(x)-\phi'(x)+l(l+1)\phi(x)=0.$$
This corresponds to $(a,b,c)=(-1-l,l,-1)$ or equivalently $(l,-1-l,-1)$. The Hypergeometric ODE has two linear independent solutions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

For $|x|<1$ and $c\neq 0,1,2,\dots$:
$$\phi_1^<(x)= {}_2 F_1(a,b,c,x)$$
$$\phi_2^<(x)= x^{1-c}{}_2 F_1(a-c+1,b-c+1,2-c,x)$$

For $|x|>1$ and $a-b\neq 0,1,2,\dots$:
$$\phi_1^>(x)= x^{-a}{}_2 F_1(a,a-c+1,a-b+1,x^{-1})$$
$$\phi_2^>(x)= x^{-b}{}_2 F_1(b,b-c+1,b-a+1,x^{-1})$$

Plugging in the definition for $x$ and the values of $(a,b,c)$ one can get the solutions OP is looking for. I can recommend *A. Jeffrey and H. Dai - 2008 - Handbook of mathematical formulars and integrals - 4th ed*. The formulas I gave come from this book sec. 22.17.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the connection formulae that link solutions about the three regular singular points to each other. There is a brief discussion starting on page 408 of my lecture notes:

http://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys509/sp2017/bmaster.pdf

Comment: Hey this is awesome! I've been meaning for years to find some more stuff  (mathematical facts and intuition rather than incomprehensible formulas) about hypergeometrics out other than they are what Mathematica spits out as the solution to linear second order DE and not gotten around to it. They look like pretty grand notes too

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.